# Temporarily allow scrolling vertically with TouchSwipe plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, swipe

I'm using [SwipeTouch plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) to hide and show `#child` element by swiping.

I have `#parent` element that holds the `#child` element.

This `#child` will not always have enough content to create scrollbar, but the problem will arise when there is.The `#parent` constrains `#child` element, forcing a scrollbar if `#child` element is taller than the `#parent`

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
         <!-- Lots of content -->
    </div>
</div>​
```

---

I'd like to allow swiping at any direction to show and hide the `#child`...

- Swiping to **show** `#child` element will be referred to as **`swipeIN`**.
- Swiping to **hide** `#child` element will be referred to as **`swipeOUT`**.

...**problem with that is**, if and when the scrollbars exist and the `#child` is visible, I can't scroll vertically because that would register as swiping attempt and trigger `swipeOUT`.

So, I had a plan:

- No scrollbar: swipe at all directions to trigger `swipeIN` and `swipeOUT`.
- Scrollbars: Swipe all directions to trigger `swipeIN`. 'Swipe' up or down to scroll, swipe left or right to trigger `swipeOUT`.

[image]

This was a good plan, except that it doesn't work. I guess if I was able to disable swipe top and swipe down temporarily, it would work...

[Link to my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/VvNhb/2/) ( the problem is only apparent on a touch device ).

[Link that is better for testing in a touch device](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/VvNhb/2/show/)

**Any ideas on how I could get this to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started thinking about the long term plan of my own project and some time ago finally got myself to contact the developer of the plugin via [github](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/issues/77)( Link the github issue page ).

He updated the plugin so that you can now change all plugin options on the fly. That also enables the behavior I was looking for. The documentation for this can be found [here](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Options.html) ( The method is called: `option` ).

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yATmM/

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yATmM/show

My Code:

```
$(function() {      

    $(".parent").each(function() {

        var obj = $(this),
            objD = obj.data(),
            objChild = obj.find('.child'),
            scrollbars = obj.height() < objChild.height();

        obj
        .data({ "swipe": "in" })
        .swipe({

            fallbackToMouseEvents: true,
            swipe:function( event, direction ) {

                // swipeIN = swipe that shows #child 
                // ( Swiping is allowed for all directions ).
                if ( objD.swipe === 'in' ) {

                    obj.data({ "swipe": "out" });
                    objChild.show();

                    // If scrollbar exists, set allowPageScroll data 
                    // to 'vertical', so that next time when you swipe 
                    // up or down, you can scroll vertically.
                    scrollbars && obj.swipe('option', 'allowPageScroll', 'vertical');

                }
                // swipeOUT = swipe that hides#child 
                // If scrollbars don't exist, swipe at any direction to hide.
                // If scrollbars exits, swipe left or right to hide ( Up and Down is reserved for scrolling ).
                else if ( 
                    objD.swipe === 'out' && scrollbars && ( direction === 'left' || direction === 'right' )  || 
                    objD.swipe === 'out' && !scrollbars
                ) {

                    obj.data({ "swipe": "in" });
                    objChild.hide();

                    // If scrollbar exists, set allowPageScroll data to
                    // false, so that next time when you swipe up or down,
                    // you actually trigger a swipe.
                    scrollbars && obj.swipe('option', 'allowPageScroll', false );

                }

            }

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the option 'allowPageScroll' from 'auto' (default) to 'vertical' (in some cases if you want) should do the trick